# Reroute onClick React Router v4 Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I'm trying to allow my user to reroute to the `<Home/>` component when clicking a 'cancel' button in the `<MakePost/>` route. I've tried several methods to achieve this none of which are working.

My first attempt was to use the `history` object passed into my `<App/>` component from the `<BrowserRouter/>` HOC in my `index.js`. I passed the `history` object from `<App/>` into my `<MakePost/>` component. Then, in a `div` in that component, `onClick` would invoke an anonymous function that would invoke `this.props.history.push('/')`. Based on what I've read, I believed that would re-render my application with the `<Home/>` component. While it does change the url in my url bar in the browser, nothing is rerendered.

My second attempt was to create a function in `<App/>` that would call `this.props.history.push('/')`, bind it in the `constructor`, then pass that bound function to `<MakePost/>`. That hasn't worked either. Here's how my components are laid out:

```
//index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './components/App';

import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);

//App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Redirect, withRouter, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../actions/actionCreators';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import Home from './Home';
import Post from './Post';
import MakePost from './MakePost';
import NotFound from './NotFound';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
 };

  render() {
    return [
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route key="home" exact path="/" render={() => <Home {...this.props} />} />
          <Route key="makePost" exact path="/makepost" render={() => <MakePost {...this.props}/>} />
          <Route key="post" path="/post/:id" render={({ match }) => <Post {...this.props} match={match} />} />
          <Route key="notFound" path="/*" render={() => <NotFound />} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    ];
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    posts: state.posts,
    comments: state.comments
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

I'm thinking maybe I need to put history in the store?

Comment: calling `history.push('/')` should indeed re-render your app. I would actually remove the `withRouter` that you have because `history` is also a prop that `<Route />` passes. Try doing.. `<Route exact path="/" component={matchProps => <Home {...this.props} {...matchProps} />} />` note `component` instead of `render`

Comment: oh wait... you have `<Router>` twice. Once around `<App />` and one inside your App's render. that's 100% the problem. you should only have one, I would suggest keeping the one wrapping `<App />`. can replace `<Router>` in your app render function with a div and I bet you it will work

Comment: @azium that was 100% the issue! Thanks! If you want to answer with that I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: As an aside: Another way to do that is to conditionally render a `<Redirect  to='/home' />` in the `MakePost` component. No need to directly use history this way. You can push this entry onto history or add a location with state if you need to. Here is the documentation for [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect).